# csv parsing and manipulation using python

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, hashtable

I have a csv file which i need to parse using python.

```
triggerid,timestamp,hw0,hw1,hw2,hw3
1,234,343,434,78,56
2,454,22,90,44,76
```

I need to read the file line by line, slice the triggerid,timestamp and hw3 columns from these. But the column-sequence may change from run to run. So i need to match the field name, count the column and then print out the output file as :

```
triggerid,timestamp,hw3
1,234,56
2,454,76
```

Also, is there a way to generate an hash-table(like we have in perl) such that i can store the entire column for hw0 (hw0 as key and the values in the columns as values) for other modifications.

Comment: Did you check the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)?

Comment: i tried some commands using panda which can slice out the complete columns which is good for me..  but still looking for hash-table part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what you mean by "count the column".

An easy way to read the data in would use pandas, which was designed for just this sort of manipulation. This creates a pandas DataFrame from your data using the first row as titles.

```
In [374]: import pandas as pd
In [375]: d = pd.read_csv("30735293.csv")

In [376]: d
Out[376]:
   triggerid  timestamp  hw0  hw1  hw2  hw3
0          1        234  343  434   78   56
1          2        454   22   90   44   76
```

You can select one of the columns using a single column name, and multiple columns using a list of names:

```
In [377]: d[["triggerid", "timestamp", "hw3"]]
Out[377]:
   triggerid  timestamp  hw3
0          1        234   56
1          2        454   76
```

You can also adjust the indexing so that one or more of the data columns are used as index values:

```
In [378]: d1 = d.set_index("hw0"); d1
Out[378]:
     triggerid  timestamp  hw1  hw2  hw3
hw0
343          1        234  434   78   56
22           2        454   90   44   76
```

Using the `.loc` attribute you can retrieve a series for any indexed row:

```
In [390]: d1.loc[343]
Out[390]:
triggerid      1
timestamp    234
hw1          434
hw2           78
hw3           56
Name: 343, dtype: int64
```

You can use the column names to retrieve the individual column values from that one-row series:

```
In [393]: d1.loc[343]["triggerid"]
Out[393]: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a solution for the slices here's something for the hash table part of the question:

```
import csv
with open('/path/to/file.csv','rb') as fin:
    ht = {}
    cr = csv.reader(fin)
    k = cr.next()[2]
    ht[k] = list()
    for line in cr:
        ht[k].append(line[2])
```

Comment: hey.. 
@bernie   what does [2] represent here ?!?

Comment: It's the third field (zero-indexed).

Answer (score 0):

I used a different approach (using.index function)

```
bpt_mode = ["bpt_mode_64","bpt_mode_128"] 
with open('StripValues.csv') as file: 
for _ in xrange(1): 
next(file)
 for line in file:
 stat_values = line.split(",") 
draw_id=stats.index('trigger_id')
 print stat_values[stats.index('trigger_id')],',',
 for j in range(len(bpt_mode)): 
print stat_values[stats.index('hw.gpu.s0.ss0.dg.'+bpt_mode[j])],',', file.close()
```

@holdenweb  Though i am unable to figure out how to print the output to a file. Currently i am redirecting while running the script
Can you provide a solution for writing to a file. There will be multiple writes to a single file.

Comment: I could, but the method might depend on what use you wanted to put it to. The simplest way would be to change your `with` statement to read `with ... as file, open("outfile.txt", "w") as outf:` and then change the `print` statements to begin `print >> outf, ...`. I don't use Python 2 much any more, so you will need to check

Comment: Oh, and `file` is, I believe, still a Python built-in (though not a keyword). Just a style point.